# Delphi Project Needing runtime Packages, even with runtime Packages off

Tags: delphi, package, bpl

My Delphi7 project will not run on my clients computer if i don't have a few of the runtime packages in the path. eg rtl70.bpl

I have *Build with runtime packages* unticked, so shouldn't they be complied into the exe?

Edit: the Project uses Jedi Packages (TJvPlugin) and running the program with out any plugin installed works fine. As Soon as i add a Plugin, the bpl not found errors reappear. Seems like ill have to live with the extra packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project may use DLLs or COM objects that have been built with Delphi packages.

Comment: Not DLL/COMs but i have plugin bpls, that might be the reason there

Answer (score 6):

It has been a while, but it seems like there was something where you needed to (1) check build with runtime packages, and then that enables some other editor (maybe list of packages to use), and you (2) make a change there.  (3) Then do a full build, and then (4) remove the runtime packages check and do another (5) full build.  It is important to do a full build each time.

Comment: Indeed. For some reason every now and then we notice that Delphi7 just decides not to build packages into our EXE and we have to go and turn "Build with Runtime packages" on, clear the list, and then turn it off again. Wierd.

Answer (score 3):

From memory:
1. check the build with runtime packages
2. Remove all the run time packages from the list
3. Full build
4. Uncheck the build with run time packages
5. Full build.

Can't test, don't have D7 anymore...

Comment: Hehe, I just saw this after adding my comment to Jim's post. Yep, we have to do this very same thing every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to uncheck the "Use Dynamic RTL" on the Linker tab of the Project Options.

Caveat: I'm using C++Builder, but I believe the options are the same.

Comment: Thankyou, <i>Use Dynamic RTL</i> must be a C++Builder Option, it does not appear in Delphi7

Comment: That is correct.  "Use Dynamic RTL" is a C++Builder specific option, it does not apply to Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

One may find this obvious, but check the size of the executable once you've compiled, if it's larger, it'll run.  When we manually copy in our updates a smaller dll is a big red flag that something is wrong with the project options.